# Excel: VBA: Paste array into Range: Keeping Formula as Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to create a VBA code, that copies an internal array into an range, keeping the formula.

I've the following code, but it always replaces my formula with an @ operator.

```
Sub rangearray()
  Dim arr() As Variant
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim myCell As Range
  Dim i As Integer

  Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B2")

  arr = Rng
  arr(2, 1) = "=IF(A1>B1;A1;B1)"  '<<<<< I want this value as a formula 

  ActiveSheet.Range("D1:E2").FormulaR1C1Local = arr

End Sub
```

So the the content of the cell(2,1) will be after the paste `=@IF(@'A1'>@'B1';'A1';'B1')`
I want to get rid of the @ and ' sign. - But I don't want to loop through the whole Range again and replace it.

(I'm using excel 365 MSO 16.0.13328.20334 32 Bit)

Comment: The @ sign is added to indicate a spill. It's something that Excel needs and shouldn't bother you while your formula works. In case your formula doesn't work, @ is perhaps a pointer as to why it doesn't but not the cause of its malfunction.

Comment: use: `.Formula2Local`

Comment: @variatus _The @ sign is added to indicate a spill_ actually no, it's not.  It's the [implicit intersection operator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34)

Comment: @sebastian this should not happen with Excel2010.  Are you sure you not using Excel 365?

Comment: @Christ Neilsen Thank you. A very instructive link.

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("D1:E2").Formula = arr` worked for me but then I had to change `;` to `,` in my laptop. Also, tested this in 2016.

Comment: Yes  I'm using excel 365 MSO 16.0.13328.20334 32 Bit. 
(The version Id I postet was the wrong one, sorry for that)

Comment: replacing ";" with "," worked for me then so far and pasting using .Formula. Thank you for your help!